# Change default action on connecting a USB device

Tags: windows, usb

I've a device I connect to my windows computer (in this case it is an iPod but I don't believe that matters).  Often when I first connect such devices a dialog will pop up giving a list of actions with a check box saying something like "do this as the default" or "always do this".

For some reason when I first used this device I selected open a folder to view files and had the always check-box checked.  I wish I'd pressed do nothing, now when I connect the device this annoying file folder pops up and I just have to close it.

How can I get the default USB action for this device to change?

Comment: What OS are you using?  XP, 7, 8 CB?

Comment: I'm using Vista but I was guessing it did not matter -- judging by your answer it doesn't.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Microsoft explains all about autoplay [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/AutoPlay-frequently-asked-questions).

1. Open AutoPlay by clicking the **Start** button , and then clicking **Control Panel**. In the search box, type **autoplay**, and then click **AutoPlay**.
2. In the list next to the device or type of media, click the new action you want to use.

Comment: I'll check this out when I get home.  Is there where it stores defaults for a specific device?  It seems only my iPod takes this action.

Comment: @Hogan - The default is stored in the registry.  There are ways to basically forget about the device.  I suggest just using wizlog's advice.

Comment: This solved my problem and the display contains device specific settings at the bottom.  Thanks!

Comment: The stored device name is shown in the Autoplay window. You can reset all defaults too. That's what I did. @wizlog Thanks for the info.

Comment: btw/fyi - This same explaination works with Windows 10

Comment: [This blog post by Rahul Saigal](https://www.howtogeek.com/236241/how-to-enable-disable-and-customize-autoplay-in-windows-10/) has some screenshots to illustrate this, which might help particularly on non-English systems.

Comment: Very useful, I'm not sure why I can't just find stuff like this in Windows but I always end up googling :)   And I'm the guy who most ppl know ask for help!

Comment: @Rob11311  I'm also that guy! Glad this game up on Google haha

Comment: @Hogan From what i know, or what my windows can do to be exact, you can ‘sadly‘ only choose from deviceTYPES.

Comment: 1. Any way to (use the registry to) let ANY program run in that moment (if not yet running)?

Comment: 2. Is it possible to explicitly keep some programs from starting when inserting disk or sth? In my case it‘s a program that has no background processes running so it should be windows that tells it.

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker -- This was 10 years ago!   This solution fixed the problem for me -- because I did not care about other items of the same type.  Sorry :(